# Is there a list of commands unique to the OS X terminal?

Tags: terminal

I tend to find out about unique OS X terminal commands piecemeal. As problems arise, or as I read askdifferent, I'll find out about handy things like [mdls](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/mdls.1.html) and [mdfind](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/mdfind.1.html).

Is there a place that lists all the unique OS X commands and gives me an overview of what they do?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Unix Commands Unique to Mac OS X / Darwin page](http://www.matisse.net/OSX/darwin_commands.html) by Matisse Enzer. It's not current (OS X 10.4.2, August 2005), but it's pretty good.

Edit: @bmike said to me things sure have changed since 10.4 so here's hoping he's got a more up-to-date resource! :)

Answer (score 2):

[ss64](http://ss64.com/osx/) has an ok quick list, but it omits many of the Apple-specific commands such as networksetup.

I also learned a lot from the [Wicked Cool](http://www.intuitive.com/wicked/) series, though I'm not sure how up-to-date that is (probably more recent than 2005).

Shell scripting and programming in any of the most common languages (perl, python, ruby etc) is just a form of writing, and [good writers borrow; great writers steal.](http://www.searchquotes.com/quotation/Good_writers_borrow_from_other_writers._Great_writers_steal_from_them_outright./243584/)  Copy and paste, run it yourself, kick it and take it apart and learn how it works.