# List of mac-specific commands

Tags: terminal

Is there a way to list ***mac-specific*** commands in terminal?

I'm very familiar with Linux but not familiar with macOS so much. I know many of UNIX commands widely used in variety of distributions such as `echo`, `cat`, `sed`, `docker`, `vi`, etc. whilst I don't know many of mac-specific commands such as `open`, `launchctl`, `pbcopy`, `osascript`, `afplay`, `say`, `qlmanage`, `sw_vers`, etc.

Comment: @fsb No. The solution lists all available commands (not limited for ***mac-specific*** ones).

Comment: Ok, then [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/53219/88313) should answer your question.  If you think you need more current info, I suggest adding a [bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) to it instead of opening a duplicate question.

Comment: Or just run `ls -1 /bin /sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin | sort` on both platforms and `diff` the resulting files.